# how to protect download file in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have some questions about encrypt. use RSA to decrypt my API, I need to download private.pem to my app document, because android can see the app folder, so they can get this private.pem file. how to protect this？

Comment: Try https://pub.dev/packages/aes_crypt#-readme-tab-

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.